# my page navigation suddenly stopped working in flutter, is there any reason this would happen?

Tags: flutter, dart

page route was working when I last wrote the code but that suddenly changed and I don't know why that would happen.
here is the page route code:

```
void pinPage(LatLng point) {
    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => pin_attributes(
              key: const ValueKey(1),
              local: point,
              userId: userId,
            )));
print("ran");
}
```

ran prints in the console, so it goes past the page route without actually routing the page

Answer (score 1):

Try changing code this way,

```
void pinPage(BuildContext context, LatLng point) {
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => pin_attributes(
        key: const ValueKey(1),
        local: point,
        userId: userId,
      ),
    ),
  );
  print("ran");
}
```

You can call pinPage() function from a widget,

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () => pinPage(context, LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194)),
  child: Text('Pin a location'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, the function was called then I tried Navigator.pop(context); to close the show dialog, and this caused it not to run properly. It worked after I modified it to first pop and then run the function.